# Transit Time in Frankfurt Airport - Short Connections

Tags: air-travel, schengen, airports, germany, connecting-flights

Two quick questions about connections through Frankfurt:

1)  SFO --> Berlin Tegel via FRA.  Ticket is completely booked through United and the second leg is on LH metal.  Will 1.5 hrs be enough to clear immigration and make the connection to Berlin if I'm carrying on my luggage?

2)  Second part of the trip (open jaw) is Budapest --> Paris CDG via Frankfurt, booked completely through United, but again, on Lufthansa metal. Since it's intra-Schengen, they have recommended a 45 min connection in FRA.  I've heard good things about LH customer service, but even I'm wary about a 45 min connection.  I know it's the reported "minimum standard" but does anyone think that's enough time?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that "carrying on the luggage" is not relevant to your first connection. When flying to the EU, customs are cleared at the final airport, so even if you had checked luggage you wouldn't need to claim and recheck it in FRA.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. 1.5 hour is plenty unless there is unusual back up at immigration or your incoming flight is significantly delayed
2. That's on the tight side. Mainly the problem is getting from gate to gate. Frankfurt is airport is huge so it depends a bit how far the gates are apart. If both flights arrive/depart from Pier A (typically for Schengen flights), than it's doable. If you have to get from/to B or C to A, you need to walk fast.

In either case LH will rebook you on the next available flight if you miss it.